# OnAfterRenderAsync never triggered in .net 8.0 RC1

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am converting my .net 7.0 project to .net 8.0 rc1 and OnAfterRenderAsync is never triggered.

Is this something that has changed within .net 8.0?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: There are no breaking changes in 'ComponentBase', so you need to show an [mre] where you believe it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

I reproduced your issue:

[image]

It now mixed Blazor WebAssembly and Blazor Server into Blazor Web App template

If you want to try with Blazor Server as before,you may try :

In Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddServerComponents();
```

In your razor component:

```
@attribute [RenderModeServer]
```

It's ok now:

[image]
Here's an [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-6/#interactive-rendering-with-blazor-webassembly) related,you may follow the steps to set up blazor webassembly

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your quick response. I do however not find .AddRazorComponents() method. Do you perhaps know which nuget package it is using?

Comment: Looking at it again. Is it possible to have ONLY a webassembly project which allows for after render? I am using localstorage, which is using JS and this can only be done on after render?

Comment: I'm updating vs to latest version,I tried with .net 8 preview version  and knew the feature few days ago.If it takes too much time ,I would answer you tomorrow--- I do however not find .AddRazorComponents()

Comment: ONLY a webassembly project which allows for after render---I don't think so .In that case ,we can't interactive with server at all

Comment: Hi,@ ChrisR,no packages are required,it was inclueded in sdk,please show us a minimal example

Answer (score 3):

This was getting annoying for me. I was not able to call a JavaScript method within the `OnAfterRenderAsync` lifecycle event. Tried many things, then came across this article. I am on the LTS version of .Net 8 (8.0.100) so the answer was not 100% the same as RC1. Here is all that I had to do.

The Server already had the following, so no change here:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
  .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
  .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();
```

On my page **all I had to do** was add this to the top of the .razor page:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

Then events started firing again.

I *am* wondering if there is a way to have a default value set. I see the following in the Server's Program.cs file:

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
  .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
  .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
  .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);
```

But that perhaps only "allows" the `@rendermode` attribute to be set?

Comment: I think you're looking for this: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-to-the-entire-app

Comment: @Robula that did seem to do the trick. I then notice that it was focusing on the pages `h1` element and that didn't look good at all and things would shift. So I altered the default line of `<FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />` to a class that does not exist (at least for now.)